# In NativeScript, how can I make a label automatically resize to fit content?

Tags: nativescript

I have two buttons with a label in between. When a button is tapped, the label text changes, but it appears to have a static width set to the width of the initial text. When the text gets longer, part of it is replaced with an ellipses.

The code is pretty simple.

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <Button text="<" tap="onPreviousLevel"></Button>
    <Label id="title" text="{{ name }}"></Label>
    <Button text=">" tap="onNextLevel"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the horizontal alignment for labels seems to make them responsive (change based on content).

In CSS this would be

```
#title {
    horizontal-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Label id="title" text="{{ name }}" textwrap="true"></Label>
```

Another way, in iOS:

```
var myLabel = page.getViewById("title");
myLabel.ios.numberOfLines = 2;
```

Comment: `textWrap="true"` did it for me. Notice the camelcasing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would be appropriate in this case, but in mine, ridiculously adding a "width:auto;" style override to the label pretty much did the trick, so far preventing the string to truncate and get the ellipsis at the end.

For example, a given TextField input (and probably many other components) with a "width:xx%;" sitting next the label will stretch or compress accordingly, depending on the label's string length, and the component's remaining space in a given container such as a horizontally oriented StackLayout.

Answer (score 0):

For NativeScript Angular:

```
<Button text="Some label" horizontalAlignment="center" />
```

The Button will then only take the width that it needs, like fit-content would usually do. I have no technical explanation for that - it is just some NativeScript magic (if you could call it so..)

[Source](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5794#issuecomment-519453301)

Comment: Please provide an explanation. See [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).